# Jquery Submitting form with button

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to add some verification to a Shopify e-commerce site so that the user has to confirm their country when clicking on the "Proceed to checkout" button. It works perfectly using a normal JavaScript `confirm()` dialog, but I want to be able to use HTML in the popup so I'm trying to use JQuery UI.

The JQuery UI pops up and stops the form from submitting (though it took a while to figure that one out) but I can't figure out how to submit the form after the user clicks the confirm button. I've found two ways of stopping the form from progressing, using e.preventDefault and making the Proceed button a `type="button"` instead of a `type="submit"`. With both ways the form will no longer submit.

**Form header:**

```
<form action="/cart" method="post" id="cartform" class="clearfix">
```

**Html code for the button using `type="submit"`:**

```
<div class="submit-cart">
    <div id="checkout-proceed">
        <input class="btn-reversed btn" type="submit" id="update-cart" name="checkout" value="Proceed to Checkout" />
        {% if additional_checkout_buttons %}
        <div id="additional-checkout-buttons">
          <span id="additional-checkout-buttons-label">Or check out using:</span>
         {{ content_for_additional_checkout_buttons }}
        </div>
        {% endif %}                       
    </div>
</div>
```

**"Normal" JavaScript code** that actually works in submitting the form with the above HTML:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".submit-cart input[type='submit'],.submit-cart input[type='image']").click(function(event){
        var x=confirm("Please confirm that you are ordering from the USA. \nIf you are ordering from Europe, please use the European store (...).");
        if (x == true) {
            $(".submit-cart input").submit();
        } else {
            return false;
        } 
    });
});
```

**JQuery code** I was trying to use to submit the form with the HTML button set to `type="submit"` using `e.preventDefault` to stop it from submitting on click.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".submit-cart input[type='submit'],.submit-cart input[type='image']").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
            resizable: false,
            height:300,
            width: 400,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Confirm": function() {
                    return true;
                    $(".submit-cart input").submit();
                },
                Cancel: function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }); 
    });
});
```

After changing the HTML button to **`type="button"`** instead of `submit`, this is the **JQuery code** I'm trying to use to submit the form.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".submit-cart").click(function(){
        $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
            resizable: false,
            height:300,
            width: 400,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Confirm": function() {
                    return true;
                    $("#cartform").submit();
                },
                Cancel: function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }); 
    });
});
```

There is also a "Pay with PayPal" button on the cart page that allows users to pay with PayPal. This button actually seems to submit properly using the type="button" method.

Comment: In your dialog confirm button callback, if you `return true` before you call `submit`, your call will never be reached.

Comment: Could you show the complete form code, for now, there is only the button inside.

Answer (score 0):

use the submit function

```
$('#cartform').submit();
```

Comment: I've been using this. Using what jaudette said, I removed the `return true;` and it performs the submit on #cartform, but that doesn't seem to be the correct one as it just refreshes the page. `$(".submit-cart input").submit();` seems like the right one, but submitting this does nothing.